# Finding the last two digits of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this problem.
I have to find the last two digits ,and if I can , the last three digits of this number (which I believe is Infinity.)

$$n={2017}^{({2018)}^{{(2019)}^{{(•)}^{{(•)}^{(•)}}}}}$$
I started by computing $n \pmod {10} $ and which I think is $$7^{2k} \equiv 1 {\pmod {10}}$$ where $k$ is even ...

Next , I tried calculating $n{\pmod {100}}$ and I believe the answer is either $21,41,61,81$ but I don't know for sure..It was lot of trial and error...

So Could you please check my answer  and ,if wrong,  provide me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: If you're tying to ask what is $\;n^{2017^{2018^{\ldots}}}\;$ then the expression is undefined unless one can reasonably define infinite powers...and I don't think that'll be easy.

Comment: The last two digits of infinity are $42$. You'd better write the expression as a limit.

Comment: @DonAntonio...It is actually 
$n={2017}^{{2018}^{{2019}^{{.}^{{.}^{.}}}}}$ and I too think this expression doesn't have any finite value.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Everybody knows that, but what are the last _three_ digits? ;-) BTW, you can define the value for the infinite power tower, as usually done, as a limit. Since it's an integer, it would have to be constant, starting from some height. And that's possible.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Interestingly, the last three digits are $666$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: "Since it's an integer, it would have to be constant" ???

Comment: A convergent function with integer values has to be constant, eventually ($f(n)=C$ for $n\ge N$). You disagree?

Comment: you could possibly look for an underlying pattern by using the mod function to your advantage. for example, 2017 = 7 mod10. 7^2018 mod 10 =? well, 7^4 = 1 mod10 so 7^(504*4) = 7^2016 = 1 mod10 therefore 7^2018  = 9mod10. hence 2017^2018 = 9 mod10

Comment: @YvesDaoust $42$ looks implausible for the final two digits of an odd number, but seems to to be very close

Comment: @ProfessorVector: the given expression does not converge, does it ? (I even guess that it diverges pretty fast.)

Comment: @Henry: infinity is an even number, most of the time. (Even if this seems odd.)

Comment: Please, @Yves Daoust, the function we're talking about are the last two (or three) digits of that expression. Have you really missed that?

Comment: @ProfessorVector: that is precisely what I am pushing the OP to express.

Comment: What an ill defined competition problem. Unless you are doing extended real number math (and if so, it is unreasonable of students to tackle that), the modulus of infinity is meaningless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Even if $2017^{2018^{1019^{...}}}$ doesn't converge, $2017^{2018^{1019^{...}}}$ (mod 100) might.  But the question really should explicitly state this as a limit instead of talking about the last n digits of infinity.

Comment: The question should also clarify that it is about ${2017}^{({2018}^{({2019}^{({•}^{({•}^{•})})})})}$ not ${\left({\left({\left({\left(2017^{2018}\right)}^{2019}\right)}^•\right)}^•\right)}^•$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's assume the power tower is finite but includes at least the $2020$ term and possibly many more

We can say:

- $2020^n$ is even, i.e. of the form $2m$ when $n\ge 1$
- $2019^{2m}$ is of the form $4l+1$, as are all squares of odd numbers
- $2018^{4l+1}$ is of the form $100k+68$ when $l \ge 1$
- $2017^{100k+68}$ is of the form $1000j+241$

suggesting the final three digits are $241$

Comment: After fixing my answer, which is a generic method, I can now confirm the last digits are indeed $241$.

Comment: True, but how can you not start with 2021, 2022, and ..... and *show that* you always arrive consistent result, 241? The case is *not* closed.

Comment: @Aminopterin I have based my proof on $2020$ being even and any (finite positive) power of $2020$ being even.  That is always true, and the rest of the demonstration follows.  And that fact is needed: the last three digits of $2017^{2018^{2019}}$ are $361$

Answer (score 11):

I will show how to generally evaluate $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \bmod m$, recursively.

1. If $(a_1 \bmod m) \leq 1$, we have $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv a_1 \mod m$.
2. Otherwise, if $\gcd(a_1, m) = 1$, we have $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots} \bmod \phi(m)}\mod m$. Recursively evaluate $r = a_2^{\,a_3^{\,\cdots}} \bmod \phi(m)$, and then calculate $a_1^r \bmod m$.
3. Otherwise, factorize $m$ into primes. If $m$ is a prime power $p^k$, but $\gcd(a_1, p^k) \neq 1$, then $\gcd(a_1, p^k) = p^i$. Write $a'_1 = a_1/p^i$, then we have $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv a_1'^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\cdot(p^i)^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \mod p^k$.

   We recursively evaluate $r \equiv a_1'^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv a_1'^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}\bmod \phi(p^k)} \equiv a_1'^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}\bmod p^k - p^{k-1}} \mod p^k$.

   $s \equiv (p^i)^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv p^{i\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \bmod p^k$ is different from the rest. If $i\,a_2^{\,a_3^{\,\cdots}} \geq k$ then $s = 0$, otherwise we simply need to evaluate bigger and bigger prefixes of $a$. If either the power tower gets too big, or we reach a $0$ or $1$, we stop, evaluate the power tower and find $s$. This is always a finite process, the tower will not be longer than $1 + \log_2k$ (this is even a bad upper bound, the real one is the tetra-logarithm).

   Then we find $st \bmod m$ and we're done.
4. Recursively evaluate $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \bmod p^k$ for each $p,k$ in the factorization of $m$. Then use the Chinese remainder theorem to find $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \bmod m$.

Note that for any sequence $a$, and any modulus $m$, this terminates, as at every recursive step $m$ decreases, and $m$ is finite. Even when $a$ is infinite.

---

An implementation in Python using `sympy` (using zero based indexing for $a$):

```
from math import gcd, log
from sympy.ntheory import totient, factorint
from sympy.ntheory.modular import crt

def evaltowermax(l, k):
    r = 1
    for e in l[::-1]:
        # Prevent evaluation of large powers, 0.1 to account for errors.
        if log(e)*r - 0.1 > log(k):
            r = k
            break
        r = e**r
    return r

def modulartower(af, m, n=0):
    a = af(n); g = gcd(a, m)
    if a % m <= 1: return a % m
    if g == 1: return pow(a, modulartower(af, totient(m), n + 1), m)

    f = factorint(m)
    if len(f) == 1: # Prime power.
        p, i = factorint(g).popitem()
        k = f[p]

        tower = [af(ti) for ti in range(n, n + k.bit_length() + 1)]
        s = pow(p, i * evaltowermax(tower, k), m)
        if s == 0: return 0
        aprimef = lambda l: a // p**i if l == n else af(l)
        t = modulartower(aprimef, p**k - p**(k-1), n)
        return s*t % m

    m = [p**k for p, k in f.items()]
    r = [modulartower(af, p**k, n) for p, k in f.items()]
    return crt(m, r)[0]

print(modulartower(lambda n: 2017 + n, 10**20))
```

This computes the last 20 digits of $2017^{2018^{\cdots}}$ in an instant as $77345043177395978241$.

---

Simplified algorithm due to user [Feersum](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/222772/feersum):

1. If $(a_1 \bmod m) \leq 1$, we have $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}} \equiv a_1 \mod m$.
2. Otherwise, factor $m$ into primes $p_i$. We calculate $\displaystyle x = \prod_{\gcd(p_i, a) = 1} p_i$ and $y = m/x$.

   Then, we compute $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\bmod x$ and $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\bmod y$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem to find $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\bmod xy = a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\bmod m$.

   Since $a_1$ and $x$ are coprime we have $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\equiv a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots} \bmod \phi(x)} \mod x$. We recursively compute $r = a_2^{\,a_3^{\,\cdots}} \bmod \phi(x)$ and then compute $a_1^r \mod x$ directly.

   $a_1$ and $y$ is a bit interesting, as $y$ only consists of primes that are found in the decomposition of $a_1$. So for a large enough $k$ we have $a_1^k \equiv 0 \mod y$. For an infinite sequence $a$ without $0$ or $1$ elements, this is always the case. If an infinite sequence contains $0$ or $1$ elements or the sequence is finite, we must evaluate the prime tower $a_1^{\,a_2^{\,\cdots}}\bmod y$, luckily we only need to evaluate $\log_2 y + 1$ steps at worst.

Comment: @user35508 I fixed my answer.