# Find the last digit of $22^{23^{24^{25^{26^{27^{28^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{67}}}}}}}}}}$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

Find the last digit of $22^{23^{24^{25^{26^{27^{28^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{67}}}}}}}}}}$ in base-$10.$

Just to clarify, I want to find the last digit of the power tower of consecutive numbers starting at $22$ and ending at $67.$ I was just wondering if there was some general method that could be used to solve this?

I don't know if Euler's Theorem might be useful for solving this problem, but it seems there might be a very simple approach.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301018/finding-the-last-two-digits-of-a-number) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) are strongly related.

Comment: @DanielFischer then that means it's a duplicate

Comment: We need a good dupe target for questions like these but I don't believe one exists at the moment. Any volunteers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\ \color{#c00}{23^{\large 24^{\Large 25^{\ \cdot^{\ \cdot^{\ \cdot}}}}}\!\!\!\! =\, 1\!+\!4N}\ $ by $\bmod 4\!:\ 23^{2K}\!\equiv (-1)^{2K}\equiv 1$

$\begin{align} \Rightarrow\ 22^{\smash[t]{\color{#c00}{23^{\large 24^{\Large 25^{\ \cdot^{\ \cdot^{\ \cdot}}}}}}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\bmod 10   &\,=\, 22^{\color{#c00}{1+4N}}\bmod 10,\ \ \text{so factoring out $2$ by }\rm\color{#90f}{MDL}\ (below) \\[.4em]  
&\,=\, 2\! \underbrace{(\color{#0a0}2^{\color{#0a0}4N} 11^{1+4N})}_{\textstyle\equiv  \color{#0a0}1^N\   1^{\,1+4N}\!\!\pmod{\!5}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\!\! \bmod 5\, =\, 2\end{align}$

using:  $\ ab\bmod ac\,=\, a(b\bmod c),\,$ the [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)    $ = \rm\color{#90f}{MDL}$

**Remark** $ $ We chose to evaluate the $\rm\color{#c00}{exponent} \bmod 4\,$ because after pulling out the factor $\,2\,$ via MDL we are left with modulus $5,\,$ and $\, a^4\equiv 1\pmod {\!5}\,$ when $\,5\nmid a\,$ (by Fermat or Euler or directly). Therefore it suffices to consider the exponent $\bmod 4\,$ upon applying [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). Applied recursively, the same idea suffices to handle arbitrary modular exponent towers.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the exponent of $23$, we see that it is a multiple of $4$, and that $23^{4n}\equiv 1\mod{8}$. So the whole expression is $22^k$ where $k\equiv 1\mod{8}$, and thus the last digit is $2$.

Comment: Rather than simply *claim* ("and thus...") one should *prove* that $\large \ 22^{\color{#c00}{1+8N}}\equiv 2\pmod{\!10}.\, $ One way is by MDL as in my answer, but there are many other ways too. Also one should explain the reason for choosing to evaluate the exponent $\bmod 8\ \ $